# How to set a hamburger menu using React-Hamburger-Menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hamburger-menu

I am trying to make a menu that uses CSS3 to fade in and out when you click on the hamburger menu. I am using the [react-hamburger-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hamburger-menu).

Although I can't figure out how to use the `handleClick` function and how to make it that when you click the menu button, or any of the links it triggers the toggle on the className.

I'm using the Gatsby react starter if that matters...

Here's what I have coded so far

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React from "react"
import './Header.css'
import { HamburgerMenu } from "react-hamburger-menu";

handleClick() {
  this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
  });
}

const Header = ({ siteTitle }) => (
  <div className="Header">
    <div className="HeaderGroup">
      <Link to="/" className="logo"><img src={require('../../images/logo.svg')} width="70" alt="Ryan B. Designs"/></Link>
      <HamburgerMenu 
        isOpen={this.state.open}
        menuClicked={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
        width={18}
        height={15}
        strokeWidth={1}
        rotate={0}
        color='black'
        borderRadius={0}
        animationDuration={0.5}
      />
    </div>
    <div className={"MainNavigation "  + (this.state.open ? 'show' : 'hidden')}>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About Me</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
)

Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}

export default Header
```

What I want to happen is when I click the hamburger button, the menu fades in, and when you click the close button or one of the links, the menu fades out using CSS3.

Comment: so, what does your code do now?

Comment: @JaromandaX right now it's crashing at the handleClick function under the imports. I might not be setting the function correctly.

Comment: crashing you say, with no error messages or other helpful diagnostic messages in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: Well yeah. Sorry I should've provided that information from the beginning.

It's not expecting the handleClick function

~/src/components/header/header.js
  7:15  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

It's not recognizing the semicolon after handleClick is being call on line 7

Comment: yeah, I think the waqy you've written the code, you're not actually declaring a `function` there - I know inside a `Class` definition you declare methods that way, but you don't seem to be inside a class definition, hence the code is not syntactically correct (i.e. it looks like you're trying to call a function, and then have a block `{}` of code totally unrelated to that function

Answer (score 1):

Beside the syntax error @JaromandaX pointed out in the comment, you're using `setState` in a function component. As it is right now, `this` doesn't have a `setState`, it's pointing to the module itself I believe. It should be point to a React class component that has state initiated:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // gatsby default environment supports class properties
  state = {
      isOpen: false,
    }
  handleClick = () => this.setState({ ... }) // this is now MyComponent
  render() {
    return (...)
  }
}
```

or you can use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook.